# how does buttons in the layer below ViewPager get Click event?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'd like to implement one UI that have two layer.
Bottom layer has one background image and two buttons, while the top layer is a ViewPager has some text for swiping. You can refer to the splash-screen of LinkedIn.
Just like the image below:

[image]

Currently the background image(bottom) changes while the texts in the ViewPager(top) swipe, this works fine. But currently the problem is: the two buttons(bottom) cannot get click event for it is behind the ViewPager. I dont put the buttons into the top layer because I want to keep the buttons static while pagers swipe. Does any one knows a method to let the bottom layer view get click event?

the main layout is below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/col_7"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slide_background" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/slide1"
            >
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/slide_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    >
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/slide_login"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="49dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/login_white_button"
                        android:text="@string/login"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/col_11"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:onClick="gotoSignin"
                    />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/signup_btn"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="49dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/signup_button_bg"
                        android:text="@string/signup"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/login_red_button_text"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:onClick="gotoSignup"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>  

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit1:
I change the outer container to FrameLayout and change the layout params of ViewPager, it seems better. If I set the height of ViewPager to some value such as "350dp", the button is responding to my click but when the height is "wrap_content", it still cannot responding.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LinearLayout and set weight property to Viewpager also remove unnecessary layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/col_7"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/slide_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/slide1"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/slide_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/login_white_button"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/eb_col_11"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signup_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/signup_button_bg"
            android:text="@string/signup"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/login_red_button_text"
            android:onClick="gotoSignup"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It seems not ok for the ViewPager does not show itself.